# Complex Linear Transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the Linear Transformation $f(z)=az+b (a\neq0),z\in\mathbb{C}.$

$$f(z)=az+b=a(z+\frac{b}{a})=|a|e^{i\theta}(z+\frac{b}{a})$$ So it is a combination of translation , rotation and magnification(contraction). We know that rotation and magnification commute  so we can apply these two in any order. Now my question  is in what order we should apply these three operation? Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just do it in the order you've given it in?  $|a|e^{i\theta}(z+\frac{b}{a})$ says translate first, then rotate, then scale.  Maybe you can do it in another order and get the same answer, but you know that way will work at least.

Comment: but translation does not commute with another..

Comment: Like I said, that doesn't matter.  The *expression* $|a|e^{i\theta}(z+\frac{b}{a}) = |a|\left[e^{i\theta}\left(z+\frac{b}{a}\right)\right]$ has an encoded order of operations (work from inner parentheses outward).

Comment: ok according as it is written?

Comment: Scaling the translation factor allows you to change the order of translation and scaling, as you did when you wrote $az+b=a\left(z+\frac{b}{a}\right)$.

Comment: Do $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Complex numbers

Answer (score 0):

*$Hint:$ A linear transformation $f(z)$ is nothing but just equivalent to the composition $T०M०R(z)$, where $T, M$ and $R$ respectively denote the translation, magnification and rotation.